# Fragments list and BackStackEntry dynamics

Tags: android, android-fragments

Below is a piece of test code in my quest to understand Fragment processing. The first output is to log the list of fragments. There are 2: GameMenuFragment and Game1Fragment0. 
Then the back stack is logged. It contains Game1Fragment0.
Then the back stack is popped. So then back stack log shows it has nothing. *Bueno*. 
But now, looping again through the fragment list, while the size() still comes back as 2, it crashes on an NPE because (apparently) Game1Fragment0 is not there.
So, apparently, popping the back stack has removed that fragment from the fragment list, yet the size is still 2.
Can someone explain?

Output:
*Game1Fragment(1617): fragmentList size: 2

Game1Fragment(1617): fragmentList: 2131492865 :GameMenuFragment

Game1Fragment(1617): fragmentList: 2131492865 :Game1Fragment0

Game1Fragment(1617): getBackStackEntryCount: 1 (0-based)

Game1Fragment(1617): BackStackEntry: Game1Fragment0

Game1Fragment(1617): getBackStackEntryCount2: 0 (0-based)

Game1Fragment(1617): fragmentList2 size: 2

Game1Fragment(1617): fragmentList2: 2131492865 : GameMenuFragment

AndroidRuntime(1617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

AndroidRuntime(1617): java.lang.NullPointerException*

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentManager.getFragments();
Log.w("Game1Fragment", "fragmentList size: " + fragmentList.size());
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
    Log.w("Game1Fragment", "fragmentList: " + fragment.getId() + " : "+ fragment.getTag());
}

Log.w("Game1Fragment", "getBackStackEntryCount: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() + " (0-based)");
for(int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
    Log.w("Game1Fragment", "BackStackEntry: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName());
}

fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(); // pop Game1Fragment0

Log.w("Game1Fragment", "getBackStackEntryCount2: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() + " (0-based)");
for(int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
    Log.w("Game1Fragment", "BackStackEntry: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName());
}

List<Fragment> fragmentList2 = fragmentManager.getFragments();
Log.w("Game1Fragment", "fragmentList2 size: " + fragmentList2.size());
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList2) {
    Log.w("Game1Fragment", "fragmentList2: " + fragment.getId() + " : "+ fragment.getTag()); // throws NPE on 2nd time through loop
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a `Fragment` is created, a reference is maintained to it in the active `Fragment` array which is of type `ArrayList<Fragment>`. An index is assigned to the `Fragment` instance, which is the index of the array element which keeps the reference.

Now when the `Fragment` is destroyed, the reference should be removed from `ArrayList<Fragment>`. If the element referencing the `Fragment` is removed from `ArrayList`, other elements within `ArrayList` might get re-positioned (e.g. if you remove 0th element, 1st element will now become 0th element). This will make the index maintained within `Fragments` instances invalid. Hence the element is not destroyed from the `ArrayList`, rather null is assigned to that index.

Here is the [code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java) which handles it. Look at line `mActive.set(f.mIndex, null);`

```
void makeInactive(Fragment f) {
    if (f.mIndex < 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Freeing fragment index " + f);
    mActive.set(f.mIndex, null);
    if (mAvailIndices == null) {
        mAvailIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    mAvailIndices.add(f.mIndex);
    mActivity.invalidateFragment(f.mWho);
    f.initState();
}
```

To keep track of released indexes, `ArrayList<Integer> mAvailIndices` is maintained, which will be used while assigning index to newly created `Fragments` in future.

Here is the code of `getFraments` method which returns `mActive`:

```
@Override
public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    return mActive;
}
```

The second time when you call `fragmentManager.getFragments()`, the list contains null for that released index. Hence we should always do a null check on `Fragment` instance before using it.

Popping from back stack will reverse the transaction. If it was added in the transaction then it will be removed and further destroyed.
Here is the call stack of a sample app I had written:

```
MainActivity$Fragment2.onDestroy() line: 53 
MainActivity$Fragment2(Fragment).performDestroy() line: 1912    
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) line: 1008    
FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(Fragment, int, int) line: 1162   
BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(boolean) line: 714
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why a null reference is maintained in the list, instead of removing it from the list. This answers 1/2 of my question. The other half concerns the backstack. Restated from above, my understanding of the backstack is that popping the fragment from the backstack simply takes it out of the navigation path of the back button, and so I don't think
 this should affect the Fragment list. Yet my test code shows that popping the `Fragment` causes the `Fragment` to be set to null in the list.

Comment: @mickey After popping the back stack, you are calling fragmentManager.getFragments() again. This returns the mActive i.e. array of active fragments, in which the popped out fragment is set to null. Hence it is accepted behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 
it looks like your `Fragment` `Game1Fragment0` is the only `Fragment` initially added to the backstack.
However you have 2 `Fragments` in your FragmentManager.
Once popped, your `Fragment` `Game1Fragment0` is released because it's not retained by anyone anymore. 
So the method getFragments() return a null Fragment for this entry.

From the documentation :

```
/**
 * Get a list of all fragments that have been added to the fragment manager.
 *
 * @return The list of all fragments or null if none.
 */
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java

Comment: So popping `Game1Fragment0` from the backstack makes it available for garbage collection, and it is collected, yet it is only half-removed from the fragment list (the size() of the fragment list is still 2).

Comment: Well you can see in the source code that getFragments() return an ArrayList called mActive. You can check when this ArrayList is modified. It's not a big deal to have a null Object in a ListView, just check that it's not null.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about checking for null, thanks for pointing that out.
I find it curious, however,  that popping the backstack causes the fragment to be eligible for garbage collection.
 Popping from the backstack simply takes it out of the navigation path of the back button. 
 At least, that's my understanding of it. 
 It seems entirely possible that one could want the fragment out of the backstack, but still want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I add this code in order to find the last active fragment

```
private Fragment SearchForLastActiveFragment(){
    int numberOfFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size();
    Fragment fragmnet=null;
    for(int i=numberOfFragments-1; i>0 && fragmnet == null; i--){
        fragmnet = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(i);
    }
    return fragmnet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
public ArrayList<Fragment> getAllFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> lista = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        try {
            fragment.getTag();
            lista.add(fragment);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
    }

    return lista;

}
```